jupyterlab ipysigma Error displaying widget: model not found
I am just trying to use ipysigma with networkx in jupyterlab as shown in this talk.
I have spent all morning trying different fixes: changing versions, using notebook instead of lab, etc.  The error is mentioned here with no replies. This error message is apparently notorious, but not specific to ipysigma.
Here's a reprex:
import networkx as nx
from ipysigma import Sigma

G = nx.petersen_graph()
Sigma(G)

Error displaying widget: model not found

This shows that I have ipysigma enabled:
me>jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v4.2.5
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\my\share\jupyter\labextensions
    ipysigma v0.24.3 enabled ok (python, ipysigma)
    jupyter-matplotlib v0.11.4 enabled ok
    jupyterlab_pygments v0.3.0 enabled ok (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
    @jupyter-notebook/lab-extension v7.2.2 enabled ok
    @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.1.10 enabled  X (python, 
jupyterlab_widgets)

I don't know if these are the only packages whose version is relevant:
ipykernel                 6.29.5             pyh4bbf305_0    conda-forge
ipympl                    0.9.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipysigma                  0.24.3                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.27.0             pyh7428d3b_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

jupyter                   1.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter-lsp               2.2.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.2           py312h2e8e312_0    conda-forge
jupyter_events            0.10.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            2.14.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server_terminals  0.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                4.2.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.27.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        1.1.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge


Concerning, 'The error is mentioned here with no replies': It is also mentioned as an issue at ipysigma with at least a vague reply.

There's something going on here with the JupyterLab versions/installs. For example, the installation here where I have it set to use with super current JupyterLab currently fails with the result like here. But the clicking the 'launch binder' badge here where currently it is set to use the older default stuff, results in a session that comes up and ipysigma works. Is providing a place it works for now good enough?

I'll note that this seems trickier than I am used to seeing. For example, with ipympl if I install in a running session, restarting the kernel along with a hard refresh of the browser page is enough to usually allow ipympl to work. Here with ipysigma, I have so far been unable to install in a running session after it launches, even using old JupyterLab Version 3.4.8. (JupyterLab version 3.6.4 is what currently launches from here where it is installed from the initialization point and works.)

Oh shoot, it seems launches from here may/will give different versions of JupyterLab depending on where in the MyBinder federation you get sent. I just got one where it is new JupyterLab 4.2.5 and so doesn't work. UPDATE: I think the image got rebuilt because I tried it quite a few times earlier, and now with new image builds it doesn't work because more current tech.

Well it isn't JupyterLab, but ipysigma works in Jupyter currently in sessions launched from here. Or simply click here to launch directly into the working session. (I made it use nbclassic and it works there. The version of ipywidgets didn't matter for 7.6.5 or 8.0.4. Even though the version of JupyterLab is 3.6.8, I see ipysigma not work in JupyterLab in way reported here.)

That's not the answer I'm hoping for, but that does seem like an answer. Do you want to post it as one, to make it easier for anyone else landing here to find a solution?

I think it is a short term answer in this case. I suspect as more people move to current Jupyter, the ipysigma developers will need to address this to make it work more consistently. (In fact, I considered posting in the issue that matches what I see that testing in MyBinder would give them a way to develop and test things to see there's an issue, but since it is so inconsistent I am not sure.) So maybe just a comment suffices for now?
